meaning of ἂν in Phaedo I.57b
I read in Phaedo (I.57b) :

(Ἐχεκράτης)
Αὐτός, ὦ Φαίδων, παρεγένου Σωκράτει ἐκείνῃ τῇ ἡμέρᾳ ᾗ τὸ φάρμακον ἔπιεν ἐν τῷ δεσμωτηρίῳ, ἢ ἄλλου του ἤκουσας;
(Φαίδων)
Αὐτός, ὦ Ἐχέκρατες.
(Ἐχεκράτης)
Τί οὖν δή ἐστιν ἅττα εἶπεν ὁ ἀνὴρ πρὸ τοῦ θανάτου; Καὶ πῶς ἐτελεύτα; Ἡδέως γὰρ ἂν ἐγὼ ἀκούσαιμι. Καὶ γὰρ οὔτε τῶν πολιτῶν Φλειασίων οὐδεὶς πάνυ τι ἐπιχωριάζει τὰ νῦν Ἀθήναζε, οὔτε τις ξένος ἀφῖκται χρόνου συχνοῦ [57b] ἐκεῖθεν ὅστις ἂν ἡμῖν σαφές τι ἀγγεῖλαι οἷός τ᾽ ἦν περὶ τούτων, [...]

My translation :

(Echecrates) Were you there with Socrates on that fateful day when he drank the drink in prison, or did you hear someone else tell the story?
(Phaedo) I was there in person, Echecrates.
(Echecrates) But if so, what did our man say before he died? And how did he end his life? I'd love to hear personally what you have to say. And in fact, there is not a single inhabitant of Phlionte who is in the habit of coming from Athens, just as for a long time no foreigner has come to us from there who would be able to give us reliable information on this subject.

My question concerns the ἂν particule: is it a particle related to ἦν (in οἷός τ᾽ ἦν) or a particle related to ἀγγεῖλαι?

if ἂν were related to ἦν, we would have an unreal condition; but then the meaning would be different: something like there is not a single inhabitant of Phlionte [...] who could be capable of giving us reliable information on this subject.

if ἂν were related to ἀγγεῖλαι, what nuance would ἂν express? Would it be a redundant expression echoing the idea already expressed by οἷός τ᾽ ἦν : there is not a single inhabitant of Phlionte [...] who is maybe capable of giving us reliable information on this subject?


Any help would be appreciated!

I'm 90% sure ἀγγεῖλαι is a 3sg optative and not an infinitive, and that "οἷός τ᾽ ἦν" is a self-contained subclause, not the "was able to" sort of construction I think you're seeing (which can't work in the context of the ὅστις).

@Cairnarvon : An interesting idea ! You're right, I thought the infinitive ἀγγεῖλαι was dependent on οἷός τ᾽ ἦν. Why do you say "it can't work in the context of the ὅστις"?

@Cairnarvon : Wackernagel (On a law of Indo-European word order, pp.215-216) analyses ἀγγεῖλαι as an optative.
